# Deserialize complex json object to custom data model c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

i got stucked when converting the json data to a custom model in C#. the json data has a structure like below :

```
{
  "id": "100002231955291", 
  "albums": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "103570756393989", 
        "name": "xyz",
        "photos": {
         "data": [
            {
                  "id": "707563939dsf89", 
                  "picture": "htp:// ssdsome data"
            }, 
            {
                   "id": "7075dfsd6393989", 
                   "picture": "htp:// ssdsome data"
            },
............
.....................   .. and so on    ......
```

i tried the code to Deserialize above json data :

```
var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookModel>(data.ToString());
```

But the problem is the rootObject also contains some Json arrays, which are unable to convert(Deserialize). My model (poco class) is:

```
public class FacebookModel
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            List<AlbumModel> albums { get; set; }
        }

        public class AlbumModel
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public List<PictureModel> photos { get; set; }
        }

        public class PictureModel
        {
             public string id { get; set; }
             public string picture { get; set; }
        }
```

*error*:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Bricks.Common.CustomModels.PictureModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: A non-trivial solution would be to implement custom serialization.

Comment: so nothing could be done with json attributes or properties to solve this ?

Comment: Well, it says in there error, there to set the attribute, right?

When you say the root object has arrays, are you talking about anonymous arrays on the root level, or arrays with names on the root level?  

I would think named variables that are, themselves, arrays would be easy to deserialize.  Just make them types that descends from List, add the JSonObjectAttribute to the class, or possibly add the attribute to the property, itself?

Comment: I just noticed that "albums" has a first object, "data" 

So in your code it should be class albums { List<AlbumModel> data { get; set; } ; }  ... and not what you have, which is List<AlbumModel> albums.

Comment: Try to use Ilist<modelname> and get the first item in the list "Ilist[0]

Answer (score 4):

`albums` and `photos` are actually objects and not arrays.

Something like:

```
public class FacebookModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public AlbumModel albums { get; set; }
}

public class AlbumModel
{
    public List<AlbumData> data {get;set;}
}

public class AlbumData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public PictureModel photos { get; set; }
}

public class PictureModel
{
    public List<PictureData> data {get;set;}
}

public class PictureData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score -1):

This method will work on any complex object:

Sample Usage: 
var complexObject = GetObjectFromJson<YourComplexObject>(jsonString, typeof(YourComplexObject));

```
   using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

   public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(string jsonString, Type type)
    {
        var dcSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)))
        {
            return (T)dcSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question that was asked.  The OP was getting an error because he did not have the correct class structure to deserialize into.  Your answer does not help solve that problem, but rather answers a different question, "assuming I had a well-defined set of classes to deserialize into, what is a generic method I could use to populate them?"